# Trying to extract value from Soap XML output

Tags: php, xml, soap

I'm using PHP SoapClient to call a SOAP service.

I'm using the following code to return the below view

```
$response = $client->Get($request); 
echo '<pre>';
print_r($response);
echo '</pre>';
echo '<hr>';
```

Here's the response

```
stdClass Object
(
    [TransactionID] => 17ACE7B75CB6SDBX
    [ResponseType] => SYNC
    [Parameters] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Param] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [_] => SANDBOX20101001123321125.168.214.72125.168.253.29912003D60E04CC4C1F8
                    [id] => SessionLogRecord
                )

        )

)
```

Here is , showing the elements within it that I want to extract the values of

```
<onlinesessionrecord><serviceid>SANDBOX</serviceid><datetime>20101001123321</datetime><ipaddress>125.168.214.72</ipaddress><nasipaddress>125.168.253.2</nasipaddress><nasport>9912</nasport><sessionid>003D60E04CC4C1F8</sessionid></onlinesessionrecord>
```

For example, I am trying to extract  from  above

I have tried to display it using the following, but I get an error "Attempt to read property "onlinesessionrecord" on string"

```
$data = $response->Parameters->Param->_->onlinesessionrecord->ipaddress;
print_r($data);
```

If anyone knows what I'm doing wrong, your advice would be appreciated.
I am sure this is very simple, I just seem to struggle with xml.

--- Next Day, further findings after help from comments ---
So, thanks to the comments below, I have now go to this point. If I use the below:-

```
        $data = simplexml_load_string($response->Parameters->Param->_);
        $out = $data->IPAddress; // same if I do the following $data[0]->IPAddress;
        print_r($out);
```

I get this:-

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 125.168.214.72 ) if I do the below.
```

But I just want to extract the IPAddress value and assign it to a variable. I have tried 2 ways

```
$out = $data->IPAddress;
```

and

```
$out = $data[0]->IPAddress;
```

Both give the same output, I just want to actual IPAddress and assign it to a variable.

Comment: Is that script garbage truly in the $response? Because its not in your code, or explained why it exists there.

Comment: Hi @IncredibleHat, I actually extracted the output via chrome's developer console, because i wanted to show the elements in <onlinesessionrecord>. I have edited the output to show the actual output, and broken out <onlinesessionrecord> to make it clearer.

Comment: So there is pseudo xml inside a soap parameter. Yikes, yeah, thats a messy return.

Comment: Yeah, i just don't know how to read it. If is was simpler, no prob, but I think my issue is that there is xml that is encapsulated within more xlm (if that's the right term).

Comment: Did you manage to extract into a variable the xml string in your question (`<onlinesessionrecord>`) or did you just copy it for the question?

Comment: As suggested here above, did you try something like print_r(simplexml_load_string ($response->Parameters->Param->_))  ? links to docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php

Comment: Hi, I have never used simplexml_load_string before, but that's cool. Using it gives me this output SimpleXMLElement Object ( [ServiceID] => SANDBOX [DateTime] => 20101001123321 [IPAddress] => 125.168.214.72 [NASIPAddress] => 125.168.253.2 [NASPort] => 9912 [SessionID] => 003D60E04CC4C1F8 ), but I'm still not sure how to pull out these variables

Comment: I think I'm getting there with your help. If I use this
$data = simplexml_load_string($response->Parameters->Param->_);
$out = $data->IPAddress;
print_r($out);
I get this SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 125.168.214.72 ) , so I think I just need to extract the array now. I'll give it a go. Thanks for the ideas.